# Can anyone explain this c++ for loop for me?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I saw this code from a book, that talks about quick-union algorithm. However, I don't quite understand how the two for loops work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int N = 10;
// 
int main()
{
    int i,j,p,q,id[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        id[i] = i;
    }
    while (cin >> p >> q){
        // how does these two for loops work?
        for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
        for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);
        if (i == j) continue; 
        id[i] = j; 
        cout << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you typo'd something in copying it from whatever book.

Comment: @PhilM How? Just compiled and ran the code, it works fine.

Comment: @SSD The logic looks wrong. Try stepping through in debugger. You'll notice that on first iteration of the **while** loop, the inner **for** loops do not iterate at all bc `id = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`. However, after that `id` _might_ have changed, meaning that inner **for** loops _might_ actually iterate.

Comment: ah, I see. This video helped me understand wtf was going on better than stepping through the code, heh. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il3Ro8yGENE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
```

Statement 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts.

Statement 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code block).

Statement 3 is executed each time after the loop (the code block) has been executed.

For example, your (statement 1) could be setting a variable, (statements 2) is your condition and (statement 3) is what happens if it loops through the function and then do `something`.

```
for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);
```

In your case the for loop sets `i` equal to `p` then asks the condition, as long as `i` is not equal to id [i], then `i` is equal to `id [i]`. Same as in the other loop, just this time with other variables.

Comment: so in this case. p is signed to i first. and if i is not equal to id[i], then id[i] is signed to i? do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @SSD Yes. But because `id` is initialised so that each element is equal to its index, those **for** are guaranteed to not iterate on the first iteration of the **while** loop.

Comment: Look at the edit I made, I made myself more clear now for you.

Comment: Exacly. So why did you need an answer for this? As you seem to know it already?

Comment: @KingReload Yes, I do know how for loop works in general, for example`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. However, in this case, as Craig Young mentioned, it doesn't make any sense to me. I start to doubt myself

Comment: At the end he just asks if `i` is equal to `p` and if `j` is equal to `q` but a way around it and then sets the variable of `i` and `j` back to the original state.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain this c++ for loop for me?

I guess it's obvious what a [regular for loop does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) in c++. The only thing that might be confusing is that these two for loops:

```
for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);
```

have empty body (e.g. they simply have a `;` instead of a loop body). This is quite confusing in this case, and it would be more obvious with a while loop:

```
i = p;
while (i != id[i])
    i = id[i];
```

Same for the second loop.

It might be not so obvious what this loop does: `while (cin >> p >> q)`

`while (cin >> p >> q)` is a common way to do input from iostream in c++.

[istream::operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) returns references to istream and result of `cin >> p >> q` is cin. When cin (or any other istream) is used in boolean context it uses [operator bool](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/basic_ios/operator_bool/) to check if there were errors from previous input operations.